# How do you change a student's name in Google Classroom?

Tags: google-classroom

Some are listed with first name first.  Others are listed with last name first.  This messes up the order of the class and is especially difficult when you're trying to transfer grades from GC to a gradebook.

Answer (score 1):

According to a Google Classroom Support post on their forum:

> To clarify, Google Classroom names, called `display names`, are set by your organization's Google Administrator- the person who sets up and provisions student accounts. If you would like to change the way display names are set up on your domain, you'll need to contact your organization's Google Admin- usually someone in the IT office. They have full control over user display names.

So unless you are the administrator, you **cannot** change their names directly.

You can also use the **Send Feedback** form in which you can send your feedback regarding this.
[image: send feedback classroom]

#### Reference

- [Edit student names or add a student ID number](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/thread/3842413?hl=en).